# Java SSLSocket Outputstream message breaks

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream

I have a problem, where a message I write to the OutputStream of a SSLSocket is send in multiple parts instead of one packet.

So, I have a SSLSocket:

```
final Socket newSocket = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault ().createSocket (server, port);
```

Since I connect to a special service, I manually send a non HTTP-standard connect header, which works just fine:

```
final OutputStream outputStream = newSocket.getOutputStream ();
outputStream.write (connect.getBytes ());
outputStream.flush ();
newSocket.setKeepAlive (true);
```

I then wait for a response, until I get a newline in it:

```
final InputStream inputStream = newSocket.getInputStream ();
final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader (inputStream, "ISO-8859-1");
final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (inputStreamReader);
```

I finish reading when I received a `HTTP/1.1 200 Ok` in a loop reading from the BufferedReader. Again, until this point everything is fine.

Then I begin using this socket to send messages from my own protocol like this:

```
outputStream.write (message.getBytes ());
outputStream.flush ();
```

When I now run a tcpdump on the target device, I can see that the socket connection is established and in fact **two** packets are send. Assuming the message would be `Hello World`, there is one packet which is marked as malformed, only containing the `H`. Then another one follows with the content `ello World`. No Exception is thrown during the run of this program.

Would could I possibly have done or missed to cause this kind of behaviour?

There are reasons for that I can not give you the complete code, but this question already contains all the significant passages.

**Update:** 
As proposed in the comments, I tried to disable the Nagle algorithm using `newSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);` just after creating the socket. But still, the packets sent are fragmented.

Comment: You are experiencing the effect of the Nagle algorithm

Comment: You could try setting the TCP_NODELAY flag

Comment: There's no such thing as an HTTP packet...

Comment: You're right, it is not HTTP packets, i fixed it in the question. Wireshark states the protocol as HTTP though.

Comment: Adding a `newSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);` in the beginning sadly has no effect on the problem. Thanks for the suggestion, though :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a TCP message either, or an HTTPS message. Why aren't you using `URL` and `HttpsURLConnection ` for this simple task?

Comment: This is part of a client that uses an open socket for communication, therefore I have to use sockets. Also, I hat some trouble using a `HttpsURLConnection` to send a custom (meaning not standard-conform) `CONNECT` to the proxy.